# Renaming and selecting columns simultaneously in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've been trying to select columns and renaming it with `pandas`. In `R's dplyr` it is pretty straight forward but when it comes to pandas I could not find a way to do it.

For example

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(128)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,7)), index=pd.Series(range(1,6), name="week"))
df

             0         1         2    ...            4         5         6
week                                  ...                                 
1     0.866637  0.263145  0.131408    ...     0.238924  0.645475  0.790599
2     0.601442  0.334299  0.119428    ...     0.109724  0.602113  0.251285
3     0.299681  0.517116  0.715203    ...     0.102088  0.706524  0.985842
4     0.559079  0.592019  0.741931    ...     0.125672  0.907613  0.573170
5     0.731224  0.301214  0.066628    ...     0.133776  0.655933  0.423496
```

then trying to change some column names

```
df.rename(columns={0 : "L",1 : "W",2 : "C1",3 : "C2"},inplace=True)
```

and had to select the columns are interested

```
df.loc[:,'L','C2',4:6]
```

but getting

> df.loc[:,['L','C2',4:6]]
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

with `R's dplyr`

just a one line of code is enough

```
select(L=0,W=1,C1=2,4:max(ncol(.))
```

why pandas is not straightforward and how can I do this the same thing with pandas ?

the expected output should look like

```
week                 L                        C2                      4                  5                   6
1   0.8666370428503979      0.041593443747687364    0.23892433469051455 0.6454746004955415  0.7905993520222332
2   0.6014424381923764      0.30913305250605294     0.10972378522258008 0.6021133114626169  0.25128495916256977
3   0.2996812876134075      0.9314494030471506      0.1020881539666203  0.7065238642131539  0.9858423635165023
4   0.5590790688036144      0.8212812049578435      0.12567153920750518 0.9076131583950552  0.5731702972368342
5   0.7312243453837555      0.16307047811396225     0.13377623506787528 0.6559325420882364  0.4234963284022535
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @AnkurSinha Hi,Please check the end of OP!

Comment: df[['L', 'C2', 4, 5, 6]] should work isnt it? Or are you looking for an equivalent of 4:6 in pandas?

Comment: @AnkurSinha You meant this `df.loc[:,['L', 'C2', 4, 5, 6]]` working but `df.loc[:,['L', 'C2', 4: 6]]` is not! and I don't want to explicitly indicate max column number (which is 6th column). Because in every data I may not know the max column value but I do not the starting column value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you need:

```
df.loc[:, ['L', 'C2'] + [i for i in range(4, len(df.columns))]]
```

Output:

```
             L        C2         4         5         6
week                                                  
1     0.156464  0.197580  0.885015  0.991281  0.478843
2     0.744064  0.082760  0.694133  0.487298  0.026765
3     0.371953  0.015918  0.494651  0.965285  0.348584
4     0.528609  0.287760  0.788897  0.664366  0.094318
5     0.316789  0.211593  0.921653  0.005872  0.174702
```

---

## Explanation:

The part you are looking for:

```
[i for i in range(4, len(df.columns))]
```

Which gives:

```
[4, 5, 6]
```

After this, it is about adding the lists in Python:

```
['L', 'C2'] + [i for i in range(4, len(df.columns))]
```

Comment: Just one thing. I was wondering does this can be done in one line of code? Such that you already used renamed L and C2 columns and in the second line we selected those. But in R it can be done only one line of code `select(L=0,W=1,C1=2,4:max(ncol(.))`. This kind of operation is possible in pandas?

Comment: and what is the `i` before the `for loop` stands for ?

Comment: `select(L=0,W=1,C1=2,4:max(ncol(.))` <- R is not my strongest thing but wouldnt this give the entire dataframe after renaming and not just specifically `L, C2, 4, 5, 6` like you asked?

Comment: The `i` there is the value of i in each iteration but putting the entire thing in `[..]` means the end result is a `list` and that is exactly what you want. YOu would typically write a loop like `for i in 1:4 print (i) and then newList.append(i)` pseudocode, but in Python you have this concept of list comprehension where you write it as `[i for i in range(1, 4)]` for example and it automatically returns the list of values in a one liner.

Comment: May be you can see a good example here since it is possible that I did not explain it well in the comments. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-comprehension-and-slicing/. If you still have doubts, I shall try to clarify it for you.

Comment: Ok I guess I got it about i for i in .... part. Thanks! Sorry I mistype of select(L=0,C2=3,4:max(ncol(.)). So it does not give the entire data.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use [`.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```py
df.iloc[:, np.r_[0, 3, 4:len(df.columns)]]
```

Comment: Just to clarify a bit, `iloc` wouldn't help with both renaming and selecting columns simultaneously, but I find it much closer to `select`, given your example. Also, [Comparison with R / R libraries -- pandas 0.25.0 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/comparison/comparison_with_r.html) might be worth reading [@alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3555558/alexander)